React-Native 0.73 and Xcode 15 Library 'RCT-Folly.common-Fabric' not found
I have issue to archieve the build in Xcode but i am able to debug the ios app without issue. This my package.json below and anyone with silimar issue and how did you solve it?


  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^3.1.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "npm": "^10.5.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.73.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.13.1",
    "react-native-notifications": "^5.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.4",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.73.21",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.73.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.73.5",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.77",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }



If I check within the pod project i can see the RCT-Folly.common-Fabric exist.

